Getting information from the server. (user-login/Next.JS)
I am working on implementing user-login in a Next.JS app (using Heroku/MongoDB-Atlas), now dealing with the login endpoint.
Here is the code for the file : .../app/actions/userLogin.js
"use server"

import connectDB from "../../configDB"
import User from "./userModel"
import {compareSync} from 'bcrypt-ts'

export async function userLogin(formData) {
  await connectDB()
  User.findOne({email: formData.get('email')})
  .then((user) => {
    console.log('FOUND:',user)
    if (compareSync(formData.get('password'), user.password)) {
      console.log('compareSync-password-success!')
    } else {
      console.log('compareSync-password-failure!')
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('Email not found:',e)
  });
} /* End of userLogin */

The above is called from a client component, like this :
import {userLogin} from "@/app/actions/userLogin"

const Login = () => {
  return(
    <form className="p-4 flex flex-col w-80 bg-slate-300"
          action={userLogin}>
      <FormField lbl={"Email"} fld={"email"} />
      <FormField lbl={"Password"} fld={"password"} />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  )
} /* End of Login */

Trying this code and following what happens by looking at the logs (server side) shows what I expect. My problem is the following :
How can I get (in the client component) the answer provided by userLogin() ?
At this point I can see this anwser (in the logs), thanks to the : console.log() calls.
I want this information in the client !
P.S.
In case this can be useful, here the useModel :
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please provide a name!"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please provide an Email!"],
    unique: [true, "Email Exist"],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please provide a password!"],
    unique: false,
  }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

export default User;

